# using Regex pattern match for pipe delimited string

Tags: java, regex

I am  trying to do pattern match on pipe delimited string in java . But not sure what's going wrong. Need help from experts.

```
A|Bill Access Key|CBEBALCOM|
D|215325775|20210507|9|BALCOM SYSTEMS LTD|||
I|1|Back of Duplex Page|
```

I have file with records as above and I want to find record starting with 'D' and get the next pipe delimited values. And store those in some POJO object.

So tried to first read values by applying pattern but unable to find match.

```
String pattern = "r'D((?:\"(.*?)\"))'";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern); Matcher m = r.matcher(line); 
if (m.find( )) { 
    System.out.println("value1" + m.group(0) ); 
    System.out.println("value2" + m.group(1) ); 
} else {
    System.out.println("No Match"); 
}
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ output you expect here?

Comment: First, remove the `r'` and `'` from the regex, since they are not part of the regex. They are characters used by other languages to delimit regex expressions. In Java, regex expressions are String literals. --- Second, since your data is not double-quoted, remove the `"` from the regex. --- Third, the question is all about the `|` separator, but the regex doesn't check for `|` at all. How would that ever work? --- In short, your regex is way off the mark for what you claim you want. Step back, and re-think what you're doing.

Comment: Please check https://regex101.com . There you can verify regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You might try it like this rather than using a pure regex solution

- stream the lines of the file
- filter for lines starting with `D|`
- split filtered lines starting at index 2
- create new array of just first two values
- and collect in a `List<String[]>`

```
List<String[]> list = Files.lines(Path.of("Myfile.txt"))
.filter(str->str.startsWith("D|"))
.map(str->str.substring(2).split("\\|",3))
.map(arr->new String[]{arr[0],arr[1]})
.collect(Collectors.toList());

} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```